# wget alternative with headless browser (webscraper with rendered JS)?

Tags: web-apps, osx, web, scraping

Is there a recursive web crawler like wget except that it executes javascript (in a headless browser)?

I just need to scrape some online documentation for a holiday, I don't want to write one myself (I guess it would be not so hard with puppeteer, so surely there must be a solution out there already).